# Using timers to delay a method

Tags: c#, system.timers.timer

I'm developing a carpark app and I want an available carpark set timeout after 30 seconds. I'm implementing this using system.timer. Here is my code:

```
internal class UpdateAvailableCarparkCommand
{
    private readonly CarParkContext _context;
    private readonly ApplicationUser _user;
    private readonly DateTime _availableDate;

    //constructor
    //...

    private void SetTimeOut{
        //set the timeOut field in the database
        var existingCarPark = _context.AvailableCarParks.FirstOrDefault(cp => cp.CarParkOwner.Id == _user.Id && cp.DayAvailable == _availableDate.Date);
        existingCarPark.timeOut = true;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private AvailableCarPark{
        //create a new availableCarpark
        var availableCarPark = new AvailableCarPark{
        //...
        //...
        }

        //After an availableCarpark is created start the timer
        //timer wait for 30 seconds then timeout the availableCarpark 
        _aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        _aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        _aTimer.AutoReset = false;
        _aTimer.Enabled = true;

        return availableCarPark; 
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetTimeOut();
    }
```

However SetTimeOut() is never called with the timer, what did I do wrong?
I've also tried to use System.Threading timer and didn't get it working. If threading.timer is better, how do I implement it? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How about [Timer.Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: @OnesimusUnboundHi thanks for commenting. Is Timer.sleep blocking the main thread? That will block the thread from creating the availableCarpark then. I would like to not block the main thread in this case.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what is not working? I have just tried your sample code (after fixing the typos a bit) and it worked.

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound - No, that would be bad. It's almost always bad in every circumstance.

Comment: @hyi18 how about [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads)?

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound - `Task.Delay` would be useful only if it were awaited.

Comment: @hyi18 - The convention for naming methods would have `OnTimedEvent` as the method that raised the event, not one that handles the event. `On*` methods raise, i.e. `OnClicked` raises the event, but `Button1_Clicked` handles the event.

Comment: @hyi18 - Can you explain more about what the timeout is meant to do? What's the logic you're trying to implement? What's the use case?

Comment: @PaulKaram that's weird, for me the SetTimeOut() isn't executing, the database is not changed after the timer interval

Comment: @hyi18 I would suggest adding a break point inside your `SetTimeOut()` method and debug it. The problem might not be with the timer it self.

Comment: @hyi18 you put a breakpoint before `SetTimeOut` gets executed right?

Comment: @Enigmativity So the logic is when a user make a new available carpark, a 30 secs countdown starts immediately. After the countdown finishes the carpark is timed out. I'm using Timer to implement this server side countdown feature.

Comment: @PaulKaram I'm not able to debug as normal since it's a deployed Azure app service, I've tried to follow the Microsoft tutorial on debugging deployed app service but no luck, but that's out of topic. The SetTimeOut function is also called in other places and does work, only not working with my timer that's why I'm thinking the timer is not right. I'll keep on trying and thanks for letting know it worked:)

Comment: @hyi18 - I'm trying to understand the use case. Carparks don't "timeout" so your description must be using jargon or you've not clearly explained the situation. Can you describe in terms of what the user, car, carpark, etc, is doing and avoid mentioning timeout or timers?

Comment: @Enigmativity Let me explain this more in detail. So a user(a carpark owner) make a carpark available to other users(non carpark owner), this carpark has 30 seconds time interval to remain available, within this 30 secs non carpark owners can book available carpark. After 30 seconds it is not available any more. I have a "timeout" field in the database for each available carpark that created, and is "false" by defult. SetTimeout() simply modify this to false. I hope that's a better explanation. I also edited the code to help explain.

Comment: @hyi18 In the current context, I can only assume that the result from the `FirstOrDefault` is empty. Hence nothing is being updated in the database. Unless you can debug the code and follow the execution, there's not much help we can offer. I suggest adding some kind of debugs in code. For example, make sure that you connect to the database and update a field that you're certain it won't fail. Try to write to a log file or any log system. Otherwise, I am afraid that this question by itself won't have an answer giving that the code works by itself.

Comment: @PaulKaram Fair enough, I wasn't sure if the timer was correctly implemented, but now seems that's not where the issue from. Thanks for your suggestions Paul.

Comment: @PaulKaram After some work around it turns out that you were absolutely right. The timer itself works fine, however it works on a new thread, which don't have access to httpcontext.current, hence not able to update the database. I'm currently out of mind to solve this new problem.